# How to exclude weekends in ionic date picker component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I need to exclude the weekends days from the date picker, I read the docs here, but couldn't find the option to define a filter function.

Material date picker has `filterDate` which is a function that can be used to filter out dates within the date range picker. as shown here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDateRangeInput

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
 myFilter = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
    const day = (d || new Date()).getDay();
    // Prevent Saturday and Sunday from being selected.
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
```

How can I accomplish the same in `ion-datetime` component?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to do this with ion-datepicker.

Why not just use Material date picker instead?

Comment: Because I am using ionic, and using any material component requires loading the whole theme

Comment: In that case you will probably have to do something like this...  [Disabled dates in ion-datetime (Ionic 4, Ionic 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043323/disabled-dates-in-ion-datetime-ionic-4-ionic-5)

Comment: @E.Maggini This is not a good solution, will I have to pass all weekends dates for the next 5 years?

Comment: You could write a function which does this. Even if this feature existed in ion-datetime how do you think it would work under the covers? :)

Comment: The max date is not specified, I will have to set a max date like until 2030, and that wouldn't be a performant solution especially as an ionic app running on mobile :( I guess I will need to do that as a workaround ugly solution

Comment: May also explain why they don't offer this feature :-D